# Android SDK Manager No ConstraintLayout IntelliJ

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-constraintlayout, android-sdk-manager

I would love to utilize the layout type: ConstraintLayout and I have been scouring SO and google for a solution but have not found one. Maybe its a simple setup issue but here is what I have and have done... I am running IntelliJ (2017.1.2) using Android API 18 (4.3.1). I am also using Maven (3.2.5) as my aid assist build environment tool. So, it sounds like I need to add this as a dependency, So I add the dependency as so:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support.constraint</groupId>
        <artifactId>constraint-layout</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

But it cannot find the version (and I don't think the type is right). So I looked within SDK Manager. I downloaded/updated the "Android Support Repository" But when checking the android-sdk extras location under m2repository, I do not see anything regarding constraint or constraintlayout. So, I'm lost. Am I missing a component here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add `maven.google.com` as a repository to search for artifacts.

Comment: so this is something needed to be added to the <repository> tag?

Comment: I don't use Maven, so I do not know the details of how you teach a Maven build what repositories to use, sorry.

Comment: You should be using Android Studio. It's an android adapted version of IntelliJ.

Comment: OK, I will give the repo thing a shot. As for using Android Studio, its a company imposed IDE otherwise I would. Also I wouldn't be using Maven, I would be using Gradle, love rebuilding entire projects for small xml changes...